# How to know device power on or off in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an application in which I want to hit a service when the device power is on and stop the service when the device power is off. Could anybody tell me how to determine what the device state is(on or off)?

Comment: Hint: if your code is running, the power is on.  If it is off, your code is not running.

Comment: yes whenever power is on my code is running,whenever power off my code wont't run

Comment: you can not acheive this without any service...BroadcastReciever recieves screen on-off (android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON and android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF)..but you have to register reciever within any service or activity....

Answer (score 0):

According to [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#MonitorChargeState) you can define a `BroadcastRecevier` like this

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                            status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
        boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
        //Start/stop your service here
        if(isCharging) {
            context.startService(...);
        } else {
            context.stopService(...);
        }
    }
}
```

and declare it in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: This refers to the charger and is not what tbe (pointless) question is about.